# Multiple sorted lists

Tags: c++, oop, sorting, data-structures

I'm trying to think of the best way to have multiple data sets use the same Linear Linked List. The data sets would each have unique information that would be held, and they would each be sorted in a specific order. For example I may have a list of people which contains their name, address and phone number and is sorted by their name in alphabetical order. And then I may have a list of transactions where each transaction has a date, item, and dollar amount and is sorted by date.

I am trying to think of the best way to do this without writing multiple LLL data structures. I am a little rusty so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  I have never used templates in c++ before but I am wondering if that is the direction that I should be going.

Comment: Have an underlying data structure that holds the data. Then have additional data structures that contain pointers to the original objects, sorted in the order you like. The underlying data structure and the sorted pointer data structures don't have to be the same type (vector, list, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking how to write a single container class that can be used for multiple different data types?

Based on my understanding of the problem, what you should use is a STL vector.  The STL container classes are all templated so that they can be used for any data type.  I suggest using the vector class since it will sort much faster than a linked list, and you have not specified any particular reason for needing a linked list.  Nonetheless, you could use the STL list class if needed.  In any case, you should very rarely need to write your own containers, especially for a trivial use case like this.

You can use the STL sort algorithm (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) to sort containers that support random access iterators, such as the vector.

Example:

```
// STL includes
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

bool personComparator(const Person& p1, const Person& p2)
{
    return p1.getName().compare(p2.getName());
}

bool txtComparator(const Transaction& t1, const Transaction& t2)
{
    return t1.getTime() < t2.getTime();
}

void exampleFunction()
{
    // build a vector of Person objects and sort it
    std::vector< Person > vecPeople;
    vecPeople.push_back(Person("David", 28, "david@domain.com"));
    vecPeople.push_back(Person("Adam", 20, "adam@domain.com"));
    std::sort(vecPeople.begin(), vecPeople.end(), personComparator);

    // build a vector of Transaction objects and sort it
    std::vector< Transaction > vecTrx;
    vecTrx.push_back(Transaction("Blue Jeans", 20.0f));
    vecTrx.push_back(Transaction("C++ Book", 25.0f));
    std::sort(vecTrx.begin(), vecTrx.end(), trxComparator);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a base node class that only has a next pointer and a corresponding link class (head pointer, tail pointer, optionally a count) , and create a set of list functions (peekfirst, popfront, pushback, ...) that operate with that base node class. Then you could add inherited classes that would include data. To use the generic list functions with the inherited classes, you would cast the inherited classes to the base class.